# ExtJS - How to Parse SOAP (WSDL) XML Response Object into Model

Tags: extjs

I am using ExtJS and I made a service call using SOAPClient as such:

```
var url2 = "https://serviceUrlGoesHere/MyService";

var pl = new SOAPClientParameters();    
pl.add("arg0", false);

SOAPClient.invoke(url2, "getPaymentsMethod", pl, true, getDataCallback);
```

My response method:

```
function getDataCallback(response) {
    ???
};
```

Here is the service response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <dlwmin:getPaymentsMethod xmlns:dlwmin="http://blahblah.com/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <return>
            <contents>
               <eftAcctNo>501014635986</eftAcctNo>
               <eftAcctRoutNo>122400724</eftAcctRoutNo>
            </contents>
            <contents>
               <eftAcctNo></eftAcctNo>
               <eftAcctRoutNo></eftAcctRoutNo>
            </contents>
            <contents>
               <eftAcctNo></eftAcctNo>
               <eftAcctRoutNo></eftAcctRoutNo>
            </contents>
            <status>0</status>
         </return>
      </dlwmin:getPaymentsMethod>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My question is... how do I add this data to a model and populate a dataGrid?

Comment: Attach an XML Reader to your Store, and load your data afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer that worked for me:

```
var url2 = "https://serviceUrlGoesHere/MyService";

var pl = new SOAPClientParameters();    
pl.add("arg0", false);

SOAPClient.invoke(url2, "getPaymentsMethod", pl, true, this.getDataCallback);



getDataCallback: function (req, r) {
    var store = Ext.getStore('STORENAMEHERE');
    store.loadRawData(r);
    store.sync();
}
```

By doing a loadRawData, it loaded the data into the Store and my Grid was able to load the data successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to load a store, populating a data grid should be pretty simple after this because you can work off one of the examples on the site:

```
Ext.define("YourModel", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    fields: [
        {name:"eftAcctNo",     type:"int"},
        {name:"eftAcctRoutNo", type:"int"}
    ]
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad: false,
    model: 'YourModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            root: 'return'
        }
    }
});

function getDataCallback(response) {
    store.loadData(response.reponseText);// or just response if that is already text in your case
};
```

Comment: You want to dynamically create a store and model based on what's in the returned data?

Comment: I can try it this way but I would also like to know how dynamically. I appreciate your help.

Comment: This is the recommended way from Extjs.  Dynamic creation based on returned data would take a lot of skill to be done completely accurate.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I am a Flex Dev so I am trying to figure this stuff out.

Comment: I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'loadData' PhoneCalls.js?_dc=1373675313519:23
getDataCallback

Comment: The getDataCallback method is inside the controller. I tried giving the Store a storeId and in the controller I added Ext.getStore('phoneCalls').loadData(response); but I now get an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'loadData' of undefined. I also changed the Reader to XML: reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            record: 'contents',
            root: 'return'
        }

Comment: just realized your reader type should be xml, I have updated my answer

Comment: No I didn't so I ended up using the JavaScript SOAP Client (url is below) and it works, but I know that it isn't the correct way of doing it, but the JavaScript SOAP Client tool is really easy to use and when I get a response back I do store.loadRawData(r); and it works fine. http://javascriptsoapclient.codeplex.com/

Comment: What works, works.  Answer this question and put what you did so it's resolved and I don't keep coming back to look at it if you get time.  Or I can answer with your solution lol.